# Basic multi-threading issue

Tags: java, multithreading

```
package demo5;

class Process extends Thread {

static int counter = 0;

public static  synchronized void increment() { counter++; }

public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        increment();
    }
    System.out.println("Done.");
  }
}

public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Process p1 = new Process();
    Process p2 = new Process();
    p1.start();
    p2.start();

    p1.join();
    p2.join();

    System.out.println("Value of count is :" + p1.counter);

}

}
```

if I declare the increment function as NON-STATIC function the value of the counter at the end will NOT be 2 million.

on the other hand, it works properly when the increment method is defined as static.

As far as I know there will be only ONE increment function for all the Process objects.. so why do I have to declare it as a static method..?

thanks

Comment: Are you sure your meant `counter` to be `static`?

Comment: you could even add transient keyword to counter and delete synchronized and it will work.

Comment: @shevchik Transient wouldn't effect it.  Do you mean volatile?  Even then it wouldn't work.

Comment: John, you are right, volatile. Why wouldn't work?

Comment: Because an increment is three operations.  Read Increment Write.  Volatile helps with visibility of single operations, but since increment is a compound it cannot do anything about it.

Comment: @shevchik You can read more here http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2007/08/volatile-does-not-mean-atomic.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declaring it static will cause the `synchronized` to lock on the Process.class instance.  So all threads running will block on the Object within the `increment` method.  Removing the static will cause each thread to only block on the Thread instance (which in your case there are two).

As a result your `counter` variable is being incremented in parallel and as noted many times, int incrementing is not thread-safe.

`As far as I know there will be only ONE increment function for all the Process objects`

There is one increment function for the Process class, but the synchronization is done on the Object and not the method for instance:

```
class Process{
     public synchronized void increment() { counter++; }
}
```

Is equivallent to:

```
class Process{
     public void increment() { 
           synchronized(this){
                  counter++; 
            }
}
```

**Edit:** To answer Rouki's question.

```
class Process{
     public static synchronized void increment() { counter++; }
}
```

Is equivallent to

```
class Process{
     public void increment() { 
           synchronized(Process.class){
                  counter++; 
            }
}
```

Comment: Ehm, you wanna tell me that the compiler creates all the class member functions for each object created..? (Kinda new to java, developed in cpp before)

Comment: @Rouki Sorry for the confusion let me word that better.

Comment: Ok.. starting to get it I think. so when I declare this method as static (means it has no THIS now) what will the "Synchronized(this)" will look like now?

Comment: @Rouki updated.  So since there is always one Process.class instance ever, the lock will block any number of instances that are trying to increment.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to replace your int counter with an [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) counter - this way you can remove the synchronized keyword from the method, and it shouldn't matter if the method is a static or instance method.